# CSS Change background color by User

Tags: css, background

i'm writing a page for a mobile version of a website and i'd like to insert a checkbox with label Dark Theme, when an user check this box change background color (of entire website) to black and text color to white, i found many part of codes in internet but it doesn't works, i don't know why.

For Example i tried this:

```css
#select1:checked ~ div .wrapper{
 background-color:black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<input id="select1" name="check1" type="checkbox" />
<label for="select1">Dark Theme</label>
</div>
```

Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: On a side note. In CSS you can only go down or deeper in to the dom tree with selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is the example of Change background Color

```
<div id= "genre">
    What do you bust a move to?
    <br>
    <br>
    <form name="music" method="post" action="">
    <p>
    <input type="radio" name="music" value="radio" onClick="changeColour('b')">Doo
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="music" value="radio" onClick="changeColour('r')">Rock
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="music" value="radio" onClick="changeColour('p')">Pop
    <br>
    </form>
    </div>

    function changeColour(value)
    {
        var color = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
        switch(value)
        {
            case 'b':
                color = "#FF0000";
            break;
            case 'r':
                color = "#0000FF";
            break;
            case 'p':
                color = "#FF00FF";
            break;
        }
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jt8h/)

Answer (score 0):

Change div background color by using css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper{
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:#000;
    }

    #select2:checked ~ .wrapper{
        background-color:#060;
    }

    #select3:checked ~ .wrapper{
        background-color:#0000FF;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
            <input id="select1" name="check1" type="checkbox" checked />
            <label for="select1">Dark Theme</label>
        <input id="select2" name="check1" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="select2">Green Theme</label>
        <input id="select3" name="check1" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="select3">Blue Theme</label>

        <div class="wrapper"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can get it through pure CSS is the following snippet:

```css
#select1:checked~div.wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input id="select1" name="check1" type="checkbox" />
<label for="select1">Dark Theme</label>
<div class="wrapper">

  Some text here
</div>
```

**NOTE**: Using JS is the correct way to achieve what you are expecting.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, i don't know why. I have a div id wrapper after body, like that. <html><body><div id="wrapper"><input with checkbox"> ALL HTML CODE DIV TABLE ECC </div></body></html>

Comment: The selector `~` selects the element after the checkbox not its parent. There is no way to do that in CSS. You definitely have to use JS for this purpose.

Comment: Oh, ok thank you. Then how can i do that with JS? To change background color and text color to entire body, it's parent.

Comment: Refer **Bilal Ahmed**'s answer. It has some JS to get you started. @9overflow